# LTSpice calculates 1.#INF for operating point

Tags: ltspice

I calculated on paper using mesh analysis that I(V1) should be 0.716A
Why does LT-Spice give such a weird result?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is explained in the LTspice Help under `B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources`.  The relevant section is pasted below, but [here's a web-link to a cached version](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/B_Arbitrary_behavioral_voltage_or_current_sources_.htm) of that help section.

> Circuit element currents; for example, I(S1), the current through switch S1 or Ib(Q1), the base current of Q1. However, it is assumed that the circuit element current is varying quasi-statically, that is, there is no instantaneous feedback between the current through the referenced device and the behavioral source output. Similarly, any ac component of such a device current is assumed to be zero in a small signal linear .AC analysis.

---

Since your circuit is linear, you should be using an F-source instead.  This requires an additional 0V voltage source in the circuit branch you want to reference, as shown below.  See the help page for `F. Current Dependent Current Source` for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is a wonderful answer!

Comment: @Kevin Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your question, but there are 4 linear dependent sources:  E-source (voltage->voltage), G-source (voltage->current), H-source (current->voltage), and F-source (current->current).  Search the Help for each of those letters for more information.  B-sources should be avoided if you can.

Comment: I still got one more question left. I didn't see there is any linear voltage dependent voltage/current source. Does it mean that I could use "bv" without problem?

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @Kevin You got it, brother.