# Simulating an equivalent circuit model of a laser in LTspice, how does it solve this circuit?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, current-source, optoelectronics, solid-state-devices

I want to know how LTspice solves this circuit as there are node voltage (vj) dependent current sources (Ist and Isp) present in this circuit. Also, I had an unknown parameter, Ne, whose value I assumed. Now for a value of Ne = 0.5 * 10^19, I am getting the following desired plot, but below this value like for Ne = 0.5 * 10^18, no plot is observed. Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that the whole circuit?  I see a `v(vph)` being referenced but don't see a node called `vph` anywhere.

Comment: @Ste Kulov no, I have edited the question. The whole circuit is shown in the picture now.

Comment: You have a bunch of feedback going on there.  First thing I would try is to always avoid using behavioral sources when you don't need to.  So B7 and B5 should be changed to E-sources, and set their gains to an expression using your parameters surrounded by curly braces `{` &  `}`.  B3 and B4 should be changed to F-sources in a similar way.  However, to use the F-sources properly you need to insert 0-volt independent voltage sources in series with Isp and Ist and reference their designators in the F-source definitions.  See here for more info:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/549958/