# How would I create an analog block function in LTSpice?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, spice, full-bridge

I'm trying to create a small-signal model of a PSFB converter in **LTSpice**. The blocks in red are what I am trying to create, essentially a multiplier block which computes various .PARAM parameters that interface with the subtractor and inverting pin of U6... Va and Vc blocks will probably BV sources, but how do I model the block {(0.5 x Ri x Ts x V(Va,Vc) x V(DUT)/La}?

V(Va,Vc), switching period Ts, and others are defined in the power stage (off screen).

[image]

Comment: Not what you’re asking about but since B3 is linear, it should be an F-source instead of a B-source to prevent convergence issues. Use the built-in LTspice help to see how to use an F-source. It’s a little weird because you need to add a zero volt voltage source as the “sense” for the current. https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/F_Current_Dependent_Current_Source.htm

Comment: Speaking about what you are trying the ask, it’s not clear to me. It sounds like you know how to use B-sources since you use them elsewhere, but the red functions should able to be implemented the same exact way. Are you running into some kind of specific issue when trying to define them?

Answer (score 1):

Use a b source and add a custom function, the function is based off of nodes so you'll need to determine if the variables are a voltage or a current. F=V(002)*V(004) is an example of multiplying

Comment: Note that current-mode B sources are typically more stable than voltage-mode ones, if you have issues getting it to simulate properly. F and G sources are even better (but linear current-mode B sources are already converted to F/G sources before simulating, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Or add series resistance to the voltage b source

Comment: @Hearth  I thought so too, but apparently not: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549954

Comment: @VoltageSpike Voltage source adds +1 to the matrix size.  Adding a series resistance adds another +1 to the size.  So voltage source with series resistance adds +2 over current source.  So current source probably not more stable...but slightly faster?? (insert shoulder shrug emoji)

Comment: Thats true if you have a large matrix, most of the time solver issues are from something reaching infinity